# NodeJS fs.existsSync() returns true for any string value

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am using [fs.existsSync()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path) to check a path beginning with undefined, such as `fs.existsSync("undefined\images\sample.png")` and I am getting true every time. I get true if I pass in any string at all, but false if I pass no value or a number.

I'm trying this on Windows 7.

What gives? Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: What exactly are you running? Are you just doing `console.log` on the result? You just have a simple `.js` file that you're running with the `node` command?

Comment: I'm running in Electron. Apparently if I pass any string starting with a letter, it's true. If I pass any string starting with `C:\ ` I also get false. If I pass a string with `C:/ ` though, that returns true. Also true with `C:\\ `. Kind of baffling. I didn't used to have any issue with `fs`

If the file exists at that path, I am displaying it in my application, and if it does not I am trying to download it and retrying the check, but the check itself is not yielding accurate results.